# Power BI - Conversion of seconds to hours in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table containing User with Seconds Spent.

I want to convert seconds into hours. And Show total hours in hh:mm format.

But the sum of seconds is 400020 which is equal to 111.116667 hour in this case 
my below formula is not working as expected.

```
RIGHT ( "0" & INT ( TableName[Duration] / 3600 ), 2 )
    & ":"
    & RIGHT (
        "0"
            & INT ( ( TableName[Duration] - INT (TableName[Duration] / 3600 ) * 3600 ) / 60 ),
        2
    )
    & ":"
    & RIGHT ( "0" & MOD (TableName[Duration], 3600 ), 2 )
```

Taken this formula from [Power BI Community](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/formatting-time-value-to-hh-mm-ss/td-p/85249)

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is there an error?

Comment: When I am using this measure then the actual hours should be 113:33 but it is showing 13:33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RIGHT` function is cutting your hour digits if there are more than 2 digits.

Based on your use case you can change it to

```
RIGHT ( "00" & INT ( TableName[Duration] / 3600 ), 3 )
```

if you have 3 digits for `hour`.

or you can just remove the `RIGHT` function for the hour part if you don't need the leading zero padding at all:

```
INT ( TableName[Duration] / 3600 )
```

Comment: If suppose my hours add up to 4 digit number then this will fail. Is their any other way? I have tried this.

Comment: Hi @Sonali Does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
INT(test[Test]/3600) 
& ":" 
& RIGHT("00" & INT((test[Test]/3600 - INT(test[Test]/3600)) * 60);2)
```

[image: Proof:]

[Download sample PBIX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcrede6kpe01mpq/test.pbix?dl=0)